# Cookies being not being set on production between server and client app

Tags: .net, angular, api, heroku, cookies

I have a web api in .NET 6 hosted on heroku with a postgres database. I also have a front end in angular 13 hosted on firebase. My CORS policy is all well configured, and I had problem with cors before, but in localhost. After some problems, I finded a solution, and the cookies was being set only in localhost (different ports). But, for some reason, my cookies are not being set in production, but I can see that I'm receiving the SET-COOKIE headers in my angular app. So, what is wrong?

**Update I**
CORS Policy in Backend

```
// CorsConfig:WebUrl returns the URL of my angular app.
builder.Services.AddCors(x => {
    x.AddPolicy("WebPolicy", opt => {
        opt.WithOrigins(builder.Configuration.GetSection("CorsConfig:WebUrl").Value)
            .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("WebPolicy");
```

**How I'm setting the cookies**

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("d_a", a, new CookieOptions() { Secure = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None });
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("d_r", r, new CookieOptions() { Secure = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.None, HttpOnly = true });
```

**Request to login and get cookies in angular app**

```
signIn(user : any) : Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl + "login", user, withBodyHttpOptions);

export const withBodyHttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
    withCredentials: true
}
  }
```

Comment: My cookies are being received as `Secure` and `SameSite = None`. I'm also using `withCredentials: true`. `Allow origins` header is well specified, different from `*`.

Comment: Could you provide some code? Difficult to debug this by just reading your description. If I had to guess, though, it might be that you didn't specify the domain for production and your browser won't accept the cookie.

Comment: Just added code, I'm sorry. Specifying a domain is strict neccessary? When using localhost I didn't need, but I was in trouble with CORS, then after solving cors policy I thought that would not be neccessary.